# sort replacing column values with NA

Tags: windows, sort

I have been trying to sort this file, I keep on getting NAs in my first column and I cannot tell why.

```
> head Coch_ATAC_peaks.bed
chr1    3181385 3181783
chr1    3389977 3390375
chr1    3456575 3456973
chr1    3661505 3661903
chr1    3903684 3904082
chr1    3916303 3916701
chr1    4316903 4317301
chr1    4322506 4322904
chr1    4402488 4402886
chr1    4416984 4417382

> sort -k 1,1V Coch_ATAC_peaks.bed | head
NA      1050187 1050585
NA      110317  110715
NA      127371  127769
NA      128207  128605
NA      13412   13810
NA      159542  159940
NA      193109  193507
NA      223382  223780
NA      233951  234349
NA      252365  252763
```

I originally made this file on a Windows PC. I converted it to UNIX with dos2unix. Any ideas where these NAs are coming from?

Comment: `grep  NA yourfilename` return any lines? if so then you really have those lines. try reverse sort `sort -r -k 1,1V Coch_ATAC_peaks.bed`

Comment: This was it! I wasn't thinking about NA's within my file. Thank you!

Comment: The -V option sorts software version-number fields like 3.0.11.2. This does not look applicable to your column 1. You could sort | cat -vet | head to show CR bytes as ^M. You could grep 1050187 Coch_ATAC_peaks.bed to show the original version of the first file in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See αғsнιη's comment. I expected the NAs to be created by sort; however they were present in the file all along.

```
> grep NA Coch_ATAC_peaks.bed
NA      2745    3143
NA      5650    6048
NA      9679    10077
NA      13412   13810
NA      39048   39446
NA      43021   43419
NA      55564   55962
NA      69578   69976
NA      110317  110715
NA      127371  127769
```

Once the NAs were removed upstream 
`> sort -k 1,1 Coch_ATAC_peaks.bed`
works as intended.